# How to use two lists, one with months, one with days, and use a third list that assigns all the correct dates for the months

Tags: python, python-3.x

question: Create a program that has a list of month names (January, February, etc.) and takes another list of day numbers (1 - 31) and assigns all the correct numbers with the month in another list (January 1-31, February 1-28, March 1-31, etc.). Print out all the elements in the list. Then Shuffle the list and print one element in the list. Make sure to tell the user this is your lucky day of the year!
ex.
months = [January, February, etc.]
days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9…31]
empty = [January 1, January 2, January 3… January 31, February 1, February 2…February 28…]

this is what I have so far:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
combined = []
for m in months:
  for d in days:
    combined.append(days[0:30] + months[0])
    combined.append(days[0:27] + months[1])
    combined.append(days[0:30] + months[2])
    combined.append(days[0:29] + months[3])
    combined.append(days[0:30] + months[4])
    combined.append(days[0:29] + months[5])
    combined.append(days[0:30] + months[6])
    combined.append(days[0:30] + months[7])
    combined.append(days[0:29] + months[8])
    combined.append(days[0:30] + months[9])
    combined.append(days[0:29] + months[10])
    combined.append(days[0:30] + months[11])
shuffle(combined)
final = combined
print (final)
```

I'm getting an error that says "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list.
Does anyone have a fix, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to only select the correct amount of days for each month, for example for January I need to use all days but for February I only need the days 1 to 28

Comment: it may make more sense to ask about the error ... your program may actually work if the error is corrected

Comment: It's giving an error saying "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list" but i'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: @Alex Ferylor Do you want to actually reorder the items in `combined` when shuffling or do you just want to select a random element? Let me know and I can help provide a solution. I have provided an answer below that does the latter. My answer also allows for leap years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted solution is great and was coincidentally posted just before I was going to post mine. However, I believe mine achieves a little more generality and attempts to answer other parts of OP's question.

Since it is possible that the year in question is a leap year, it could be useful to also test for this. I have also added code to randomly select a day from the year. I was not sure if you actually wanted to reorder the list with `shuffle` or if you just wanted to select a random element from the list.

```
from random import randrange

# key: value <-> month: days in months
months = {
    "January": 31,
    "February": 28,
    "March": 31,
    "April": 30,
    "May": 31,
    "June": 30,
    "July": 31,
    "August": 31,
    "September": 30,
    "October": 31,
    "November": 30,
    "December": 31
    }

# year
year = 1996

# check if leap year (1996 is) 
if (year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)):
    months["February"] = 29
    days_in_year = 366
else:
    months["February"] = 28
    days_in_year = 365

# list with days in year
combined = []
for month in months:
    for i in range(1, months[month] + 1):
        combined.append(f"{month} {i}")

# select random element from list
r = combined[randrange(0, len(combined))]
print(f"Your lucky day is {r}")
```

Example output

```
Your lucky day is April 29
```